# copy data from a text.rpt file to paste it postgresql in pgadmin

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

When I run:

```
COPY con (date,kgs) 
FROM 'H:Sir\\data\\reporting\\hi.rpt'
WITH DELIMITER ','
CSV HEADER 
    date AS 'Datum/Uhrzeit'
    kgs  AS 'Summe'
```

I get the error:

```
WARNING:  nonstandard use of \\ in a string literal
LINE 2: FROM 'H:Sudhir\\Conair data\\TBreporting\\hi.txt'
             ^
HINT:  Use the escape string syntax for backslashes, e.g., E'\\'.
```

I've been having this problem for quite a while. Help?

Comment: Your question is totally unclear. Please clarify it.

Comment: What is a "text.rpt" file? What application created it? What format is it - is it just CSV or is it something else? What PostgreSQL version are you using?

Comment: is `hi.rpt` a `crystal report` file ??

Comment: "hi.rpt" is a report generated by a software. i want to extract specific data from this report like date n weight n put them in database for evaluation.

Comment: I am using postgreSQL 9.0

Comment: "a software". **What software**? What are the file contents? Show a few sample lines.

Comment: I don't know the software name. what i have is this .rpt file and about how the file look like i have shown few lines text of the file above

Comment: OK, so it's just comma-separated data, and the `.rpt` extension is probably some genius's clever idea for "report".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not an error, it's just a warning. It has nothing to do with the file content, it's related to a PostgreSQL setting and the `COPY` command syntax you're using.

You're using PostgreSQL after 8.1 with `standard_conforming_strings` turned off - either before 9.1 (which defaulted to off) or a newer version with it turned off manually.

This causes backslashes in strings, like `bob\ted`, get interpreted as escapes, so that string would be `bob<tab>ted` with a literal tab, as `\t` is the escape for a tab.

Interpreting strings like this is contrary to the SQL standard, which doesn't have C-style backslash escapes. Years ago the PostgreSQL team decided to switch to the SQL standard way of doing things. For backward compatibility reasons it was done in two stages:

- Add the `standard_conforming_strings` option to use the SQL-standard interpretation of strings, but have it default to off. Issue warnings when using the non-standard PostgreSQL string interpretation. Add a new `E'string'` style to allow applications to explicitly request escape processing in strings.
- A few releases later, turn `standard_conforming_strings` on by default, once people had updated and fixed the warnings their applications produced. Supposedly.

The escape for `\` is `\\`. So "doubling" the backslashes like you (or the tool you're using) done is correct. PostgreSQL is showing a warning because it doesn't know if when you wrote `H:Sir\\data\\reporting\\hi.rpt` you meant literally `H:Sir\\data\\reporting\\hi.rpt` (like the SQL spec says) or `H:Sir\data\reporting\hi.rpt` (like PostgreSQL used to do, against the standard).

Thus there's nothing wrong with your query. If you want to get rid of the warning, either turn `standard_conforming_strings` on , or add an explicit `E''` to your string.

Comment: Thanks Craig i have turned on standard_conforming_strings.

Comment: i have few other problems also with the same thing i have edited my question and given all the details also please have a look.

Comment: @user3732694 Please undo the edit and post as a *new question*. Link back to this one for context.

Comment: i have asked a new question but 'a_horse_with_no_name' marked my question as duplicate. the thing is i still didn't got the answer can you help me.

Comment: @user3732694 Reopened and answered. Please accept this one, since it answered the question you asked.