# COPY only some columns from an input CSV?

Tags: postgresql

I have created a table in my database with name 'con' which has two columns with the name 'date' and 'kgs'. I am trying to extract data from this 'hi.rpt' file copied on this location 'H:Sir\data\reporting\hi.rpt' and want to store values in the table 'con' in my database.

I have tried this code in pgadmin

When I run:

```
COPY con (date,kgs) 
FROM 'H:Sir\data\reporting\hi.rpt'
WITH DELIMITER ','
CSV HEADER 
    date AS 'Datum/Uhrzeit'
    kgs  AS 'Summe'
```

I get the error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "date"
LINE 5:    date AS 'Datum/Uhrzeit' 
           ^
********** Error **********
ERROR: syntax error at or near "date"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 113
```

"hi.rpt" file from which i am reading the data look like this:

```
Datum/Uhrzeit,Sta.,Bez.,Unit,TBId,Batch,OrderNr,Mat1,Total1,Mat2,Total2,Mat3,Total3,Mat4,Total4,Mat5,Total5,Mat6,Total6,Summe
41521.512369(04.09.13 12:17:48),TB01,TB01,005,300,9553,,2,27010.47,0,0.00,0,0.00,3,1749.19,0,0.00,0,0.00,28759.66
41521.547592(04.09.13 13:08:31),TB01,TB01,005,300,9570,,2,27057.32,0,0.00,0,0.00,3,1753.34,0,0.00,0,0.00,28810.66
```

Is it possible to extract only two data values from 20 different type of data that i have in this 'hi.rpt' file or not?

or is there only a mistake in the syntax that i have written?
What is the correct way to write it?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I disagree with marking this a dup. It's a different question on a different topic, it just involves the same base data.

Comment: @CraigRinger: [the other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24465965/copy-data-from-a-text-rpt-file-to-paste-it-postgresql-in-pgadmin) is an **exact** duplicate of this one. The bodies of the questions are identical, the only difference is the subject/title.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Ah. Yes, when I asked them to revert their changes, they instead deleted the original question entirely, leaving just the rewritten one. Argh. Fixed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know where you got that syntax, but `COPY` doesn't take a list of column aliases like that. See the help:

```
COPY table_name [ ( column_name [, ...] ) ]
    FROM { 'filename' | PROGRAM 'command' | STDIN }
    [ [ WITH ] ( option [, ...] ) ]
```

(`AS` isn't one of the listed options; to see the full output run `\d copy` in psql, or look at the manual for the `copy` command online).

There is no mapping facility in `COPY` that lets you read only some columns of the input CSV. It'd be really useful, but nobody's had the time/interest/funding to implement it yet. It's really only one of many data transform/filtering tasks people want anyway.

PostgreSQL expects the column-list given in `COPY` to be in the same order, left-to-right, as what's in the CSV file, and have the same number of entries as the CSV file has columns. So if you write:

```
COPY con (date,kgs)
```

then PostgreSQL will expect an input CSV with *exactly two columns*. It'll use the first csv column for the `"date"` table column and the second csv column for the `"kgs"` table column. It doesn't care what the CSV headers are, they're ignored if you specify `WITH (FORMAT CSV, HEADER ON)`, or treated as normal data rows if you don't specify `HEADER`.

PostgreSQL 9.4 adds `FROM PROGRAM` to `COPY`, so you could run a shell command to read the file and filter it. A simple Python or Perl script would do the job.

If it's a small file, just open a copy in the spreadsheet of your choice as a csv file, delete the unwanted columns, and save it, so only the `date` and `kgs` columns remain.

Alternately, `COPY` to a staging table that has all the same columns as the `CSV`, then do an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` to transfer just the wanted data into the real target table.

Comment: that means if i want to move this data to database i have to take all the columns and have to give the exact same name as the name used in text file????

Comment: I have got that syntax from [postgreSql](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/sql-copy.html)

Comment: @user3732694 You must've completely misunderstood the documentation, it doesn't show anything like the syntax you used (re `date AS 'Datum/Uhrzeit'`). Those entries like `DELIMITER [ AS ] 'delimiter'` have special meaning explained in the document below, it's not just an example showing the mapping of a csv field named `DELIMITER` to a table column named `delimiter`. You can't write `mycsvcolumn AS 'mytablecolumn'`.

Comment: @user3732694 Added more info about columns to the answer, see edit. Short version: The names of columns in the csv are completely ignored. PostgreSQL just takes columns left-to-right in the order specified in the list of column names in your `copy tablename(col1, col2, ...)`. There must be the same number of CSV columns as specified table columns. If you want to do something fancier, look into ETL tools like Pentaho Kettle, Talend Studio, or CloverETL.

Comment: it still not working. I have tried it all. I have created a new text file with two values n created a table with two column with the same name a data headings still it doesn't work at all. It will be helpful if u try it once n see it works.

Comment: @user3732694 and the error message is now .... ? Also, I don't understand what you're asking me to try.

Comment: yes it finally worked. i have created a new text file and tried it for that text file and it worked on that. But it is still giving error in my 'hi.rpt' i don't kw under which data type should i put  "Datum/Uhrzeit" --> "41521.512369(04.09.13 12:17:48)".