# data extraction from .rpt file to copy in database in PostgreSQL 9.0

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql, pgadmin

I have a report file(.rpt) having text as shown below and this .rpt file get updated every day.

```
Datum/Uhrzeit,Sta.,Bez.,Unit,TBId,Batch,OrderNr,Mat1,Total1,Mat2,Total2,Mat3,Total3,Mat4,Total4,Mat5,Total5,Mat6,Total6,Summe
41521.755934(04.09.13 18:08:32),TB01,TB01,005,300,9663,        ,2,27313.63,0,0.00,0,0.00,3,1776.19,0,0.00,0,0.00,29089.82
41521.797601(04.09.13 19:08:32),TB01,TB01,005,300,9682,        ,2,27365.98,0,0.00,0,0.00,3,1780.86,0,0.00,0,0.00,29146.85
41521.839269(04.09.13 20:08:32),TB01,TB01,005,300,9701,        ,2,27418.34,0,0.00,0,0.00,3,1785.53,0,0.00,0,0.00,29203.88
41521.880937(04.09.13 21:08:33),TB01,TB01,005,300,9721,        ,2,27473.31,0,0.00,0,0.00,3,1790.40,0,0.00,0,0.00,29263.71
41521.922606(04.09.13 22:08:33),TB01,TB01,005,300,9741,        ,2,27528.53,0,0.00,0,0.00,3,1795.30,0,0.00,0,0.00,29323.83
41521.964274(04.09.13 23:08:33),TB01,TB01,005,300,9760,        ,2,27580.88,0,0.00,0,0.00,3,1799.97,0,0.00,0,0.00,29380.84
41522.005942(05.09.13 00:08:33),TB01,TB01,005,300,9780,        ,2,27636.00,0,0.00,0,0.00,3,1804.86,0,0.00,0,0.00,29440.86
```

Need to extract first and last reading values of every row and need to put that reading in database table.

first reading -- Datum/Uhrzeit

last reading  -- Summe

I have used COPY command also but it doesn't take the first value. I want to know which data type to use to extract this value (it is not in normal date formats)???

Also is it not possible just to take these two readings only out of this file and not the whole 20 readings?? Is there any such method available??

I am using PostgreSQL 9.0

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that "reading" = "column":

You will need to `COPY` to a `TEMPORARY` table where the first column is of type `text`, not `date`, since that is an invalid date format.

Then you can do an `INSERT INTO teal_table (col1, col2, ...) SELECT some_func(thedate), col2, col3... FROM temptable` to transform the temp table contents into correct date data using appropriate SQL and insert it into the real target table.

There are lots of existing examples of this on Stack Overflow, though not for your particular date format. I'm guessing that the date in the parens `(...)` is the date you want, and that the numbers before are a representation of that date as days since epoch + time since start of day. It'll be easier to just parse the date part, which you can do with:

```
SELECT to_timestamp(substring('41521.880937(04.09.13 21:08:33)' from '\(.*\)' ), '(DD.MM.YY HH24.MI.SS)');
```

so that's your `some_func` for the above.

As for taking only the two desired columns, [I already explained that to you before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24483582/copy-only-some-columns-from-an-input-csv) so I'm not going to repeat myself. Short version: Use an ETL tool, re-export the CSV with just those columns, or use a filter program to limit the input.

Comment: thanks a lot your answer has solved my problem. Just a small thing the function to_timestamp its gives output in timestamp with time zone.   statement---->            select to_timestamp(substr("Datum/Uhrzeit", 14, 30), 'dd.mm.yy hh24:mi:ss') in_date from file;    output is --> "2013-09-04 12:17:48+05:30"  if i have to remove this "+5:30" then what can i do i have tried some other functions also related to this but they also didn't give the correct form in output